# When should I add (auto-scale) new Nginx server instances?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, capacity-planning

Should I take in consideration CPU utilization, network traffic or http response time checks? I've run some tests with Apache AB (from the same server - eq:  ab -k -n 500000 -c 100 http://192.XXX.XXX.XXX/) - and I monitored the load average. Even if the load was between 1.0 - 1.50(one core server), "time per request"(mean) was pretty solid, 140ms for a simple dynamic page with one set/get Redis operation. Anyway, I'm confused as the general advice is to launch a new instance when you pass the 70% CPU utilization threshold.

Comment: Is that the amount of your average traffic / concurrent users ?

Comment: Is just a test, the server is not in production yet. For  ab -k -n 500000 -c 1500 I get a time per request of 589ms(mean). For -c 2000 850ms. The load average stays somewhere between 1.30-1.50 for all tests, it doesn't matter if I have a concurrency of 100, 1500 or 2000. This makes me wonder if the load average is a good metric for deciding when to add or to remove new instances.

Answer (score 1):

70% CPU utilization is a good rule of thumb for CPU-bound applications like nginx. CPU time is kind of like body temperature: it actually hides a lot of different things, but is a good general indicator of health. Load average is a separate measure of how many processes are waiting to be scheduled. The reason the rule is 70% (or 80%) utilization is that, past this point, CPU-bound appliations tend to suffer contention-induced latency and non-linear performance.

You can test this yourself by plotting throughput and latency (median and 90th percentile) against CPU utilization on your setup. Finding the inflection point for your particular system is important for capacity planning.

A very good writeup of this phenomenon is given in Facebook's original paper on Dyno, their system for measuring throughput of PHP under load.

https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=203367363919